# Why doesn't my code work when I write "G->Adj[i]" but works on writing "G->Adj+i" in graph implementation (Adjacency List).?

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Graph* GraphList();
struct Listnode
{
     int vertex;
     struct Listnode*next;
};
struct Graph
{
  int V;
  int E;
  struct Listnode *Adj;
};
void main()
{
    struct Graph *G=NULL;
    int i;
    struct Listnode *temp=NULL;
    printf("Program to Implement graph using Adjacency List\n");
    G=GraphList();
     for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
     {
         temp=G->Adj+i;
         while((temp->next)!=(G->Adj+i))
            {
                printf("%d-->",temp->vertex);
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        printf("%d",temp->vertex);
        printf("\n");
     }
}
struct Graph* GraphList()
{
     int i,j,x,y;
     struct Listnode *t,*temp;
      struct Graph *G;
      G=(struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
      printf("Enter the no.of vertices and Edges respectively\n");
      scanf("%d %d",&G->V,&G->E);
      G->Adj=(struct Listnode*)malloc((sizeof(struct Listnode))*G->V);  //Undirected Graph
      for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
      {
          (G->Adj+i)->vertex=i+1;
       (G->Adj+i)->next= (G->Adj+i);
      }
      for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
      {
          t= (G->Adj+i);
          printf("Enter number of neigbouring nodes to node-%d  ",i+1);
          scanf("%d",&x);
          for(j=0;j<x;j++)
          {
          printf("Enter the vertex number-%d that is neighbour to node -%d  ",j+1,i+1);
              scanf("%d",&y);
              temp=(struct Listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct Listnode));
              temp->vertex=y;
              temp->next= G->Adj+i;
              while(t->next!= (G->Adj+i))
                     t=t->next;
              t->next=temp;
          }
      }
      return G;
}
```

The above code works fine, but when I replace "G->Adj+i" with "G->Adj[i]" it doesn't work. I have created array of type "struct Listnode" (let's say size-5) and and stored it in "G->Adj", and I feel it is fair to use "G->Adj[i]" but I don't understand why error message pops-up as:

`"D:\DataStructures by SS\Graph Link (standard).c|60|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct Listnode *' from type 'struct Listnode'|  ".`

Please explain.

Comment: Maybe you need to have a double pointer for `Adj`, like `struct Listnode **Adj;`. So it will be a dynamic array of pointers to `Listnode`s.

Comment: Which one is line 60?

Comment: `G->Adj[i]` returns element, but you need address of element, which you can get using `&G->Adj[i]`

Answer (score 0):

`G->Adj+i` is equivalent to `&G->Adj[i]`. The leading ampersand is required to undo `[i]`'s dereference.